# Can you force a touch event to cancel after touchesBegan?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Given a certain state of one of my UIViews I'd like it to respond to touchesBegan and then cancel any further touchesMoved/Ended that continue from that particular touchesBegan event.

Basically I have an UIView subclass at rest and if it's touched I'd like to move some other UIViews out of the way... then the next time it's touched the responder chain can respond normally to touchesMoved/Ended...

yes, i could check for this state in touchesMoved/Ended but I'm wondering if there's a way to just derail that touch event mid-phase.

Answer (score 1):

```
    let fakeTouch:Set<NSObject> = [UITouch()]
    let event     = UIEvent()

    self.touchesEnded(fakeTouch, withEvent: event)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for why your code works so that future users can easily understand it.

Answer (score 1):

**Remove the view for the view hierarchy**

This is a very old post without a convincing answer, so I decided to add my workaround

Working with Xcode 9, Swift 4 and iOS 11, these solutions don't interrupt the touch

```
self.resignFirstResponder()
self.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
```

The work around I found is the following:

```
let superview = self.superview
self.removeFromSuperview()
superview?.addSubview(self)
```

This is easy to implement in code only projects. I did not test it using views in `Storyboard`.

You would need to make sure you manage the view hierarchy, in case you can to restore o the view in the same point in the subviews stack. I assign tags to views to manage the position in the `superview.subviews` array

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it, but I take a educated guess.

The first responder is the current recipient of touch events. So resigning as first responder should stop more touch events from coming in. A new touch down will set a new first responder.

```
[self resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Educated guess was good, OP doing the work of testing it was okay, not responding to the results and deleting or fixing your answer -1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have one touch, the touch object is always the same, meaning that you can compare using `==`

```
UITouch *anyTouch = [touches anyObject];
if (anyTouch != self.lastTouch)
     return;
```

So, by storing the last `UITouch` in your `UIView` subclass (in the example I use a property called `lastTouch`), you can figure out which touches you want to ignore and which you want to recognize on your moved and ended/cancelled. Not elegant and not that direct, but it lets you get at what you want.

This can be expanded for multiple touches, of course.

Answer (score -2):

as far as I know, the UIScrollView is able to cancel touches. So I guess there is some way to do that. Sorry I can't provide a more precise solution.